# How to write a file for Django FileField - preventing duplicate files

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I have the following code to save a base64 encoded screenshot as a .png .

```
class SupportTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SupportTicket
        fields = ('message',
                  'created_by',
                  'modified_by')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.img_data_base64 = kwargs.pop('img_data_base64')
        except KeyError, e:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('SupportTicket was not properly instantiated. The following keyword argument is missing: %s:' %(e))
        super(SupportTicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        ticket = super(SupportTicketForm, self).save(commit=False)
        date_now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        #dummy-name will be set to unique name in upload handler in models.py
        filename = "dummy-name.png"
        fh = open(filename, 'w+b')
        img_file = File(fh)
        img_file.write(self.img_data_base64.decode('base64'))
        ticket.ticket_img.save(filename, img_file)
        fh.close()
        if commit:
            ticket.save()
        return ticket
```

The model looks like this:

```
def support_ticket_path_handler(instance, filename):
    year = datetime.now().year
    month = datetime.now().month
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    #rename filename - create random + unique filename
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    path_return = "support/tickets/{year}/{month}/{file}".format(year=year,
                                                                 month=month,
                                                                 file=filename)
    return path_return

support_ticket_storage = FileSystemStorage()
class SupportTicket(models.Model):
    """user created support tickets"""
    INITIAL_STATUS = 0
    IN_PROGRESS_STATUS = 1
    RESOLVED_STATUS = 2
    DEFAULT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (INITIAL_STATUS, 'New Ticket'),
        (IN_PROGRESS_STATUS, 'In Progress'),
        (RESOLVED_STATUS, 'Resolved'),
    )

    message = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    ticket_img  = models.FileField(storage=support_ticket_storage,
                                   upload_to=support_ticket_path_handler,
                                   blank=False)
```

My issue is that the code in the form save() method creates two files on the disk. One file named `"dummy-name.png"` and one file named like defined in `support_ticket_path_handler`, whereas I only need the second one.

As I need a python image file handle for the Django File object I do not understand how to prevent the creation of the first image. An option would be to delete the first image afterwards, but that does not look very clean to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `StringIO` instead:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import base64

data = StringIO(base64.decodestring(self.img_data_base64))
img_file = File(data)
ticket.ticket_img.save(filename, img_file)
```

`StringIO` treats your data as if it were file while it keeps it in memory.

Comment: If anyone else was wondering (as I was) the `File` in `File(data)`  is the django core File object. You can import with `from django.core.files import File`